# UIGestureRecognizer subclass-- touchesMoved automatically changes state to .changed

Tags: ios, swift, uigesturerecognizer

I am trying to create a `UIGestureRecognizer` subclass, and in `touchesMoved` I have no code, yet `state` is being set to `.changed`.

Does anyone know why this is happening? I need to be able to decide for myself when we are in the `.changed` state.

If I remove my `touchesBegan` function and never move to `.began`, this doesn't happen.

```
import UIKit.UIGestureRecognizerSubclass

class MyRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer {

    private var refView: UIView? {
        return self.view?.window
    }


    override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent) {
       super.touchesBegan(touches, with: event)

       if touches.count != 1 {
            state = .failed
            return
        }

        guard let location = touches.first?.location(in: refView) else {
            self.state = .failed
            return
        }

       state = .began

    }

    override func touchesMoved(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent) {
        // there is no code here!
    }

   //This is how I'm debugging state
   override var state: UIGestureRecognizerState {
      get { return super.state }
      set {
          super.state = newValue
          print("state = \(newValue.debugDescription)")
      }  
    }

}

extension UIGestureRecognizerState: CustomDebugStringConvertible {
    public var debugDescription: String {
        switch self {
        case .began: return "began"
        case .possible: return "possible"
        case .changed: return "changed"
        case .ended: return "ended"
        case .cancelled: return "cancelled"
        case .failed: return "failed"
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your testing approach is flawed. I tried this (this is my test app's complete code):

```
import UIKit
import UIKit.UIGestureRecognizerSubclass

class MyRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer {
    override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent) {
        super.touchesBegan(touches, with: event)
        print(self.state.rawValue)
    }
    override func touchesMoved(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent) {
        super.touchesMoved(touches, with: event)
        print(self.state.rawValue)
    }
}

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        let g = MyRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(grFired))
        self.view.addGestureRecognizer(g)
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }

    @objc func grFired(_ g:UIGestureRecognizer) {
        print("here", g.state.rawValue)
    }

}
```

Then I dragged on the background view, to which the gesture recognizer is attached. My gesture recognizer never moved from the `possible` state.

Also note that your expectations may be incorrect ("I need to be able to decide for myself when we are in the .changed state"). The normal and correct behavior is that, having declared the state to be `.began` in `touchesBegan`, your `touchesMoved` will be called once with state `.began` and the gesture recognizer will immediately advance to `.changed` automatically. That is *correct*; if this is continuous gesture, it cannot be the case that a `moved` event should come in while we are in `.began` state without our proceeding to `.changed`. Again, here's a test:

```
import UIKit
import UIKit.UIGestureRecognizerSubclass

class MyRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer {
    override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent) {
        super.touchesBegan(touches, with: event)
        if touches.count != 1 {
            state = .failed
            return
        }
        print(self.state.rawValue)
        self.state = .began
    }
    override func touchesMoved(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent) {
        super.touchesMoved(touches, with: event)
        print("moved", self.state.rawValue)
    }
}

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        let g = MyRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(grFired))
        self.view.addGestureRecognizer(g)
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }

    @objc func grFired(_ g:UIGestureRecognizer) {
        print("here", g.state.rawValue)
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately I tried that with no luck. I removed it from my example above to show I was not even touching the superclass. I'll add it back in to be more clear.

Comment: See my revised answer.

Comment: Thanks. I see now-- very helpful. What I was trying to do is not move to .changed unless the touch moved by a certain minimum amount.

Comment: All I have to do is check first before moving to .began. Which makes sense, semantically speaking, given your explanation. Cheers.

Comment: Correct. If this isn't your gesture, fail! Apple says: "Fail early, fail often." You should probably never have changed to `.began` in the first place. If it _is_ your gesture, it makes no sense to want anything but `.began` followed by `.changed`.